# Does the interaction picture assume that the Hamiltonians commute?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, propagator

Suppose the Hamiltonian is $H+H_1(t)$. In the Schrodinger picture, the evolution is:

$$|\psi(t)\rangle=e^{i(Ht+\int_0^tH_1(t)dt)}|\psi(0)\rangle$$.

The interaction picture introduces a change of basis $e^{-iHt}$ at time $t$. This makes the operators at time $t$:

$$\Omega (t)=e^{-iHt}\Omega (0)e^{iHt}$$

And the state vector at time $t$ in the new basis would be:

$$|\psi _I (t)\rangle= e^{-iHt}e^{iHt+i\int_0^t H_1(t)dt} |\psi (0)\rangle $$

$$=e^{i\int_0^t H_1 (t)dt}|\psi(0) \rangle $$

The last step relies on $$e^Ae^B=e^{A+B}$$. Isn't this assuming that $A$ and $B$ commute? Please help.

Comment: Actually even your expression for $|\psi(t)\rangle$ in Schrodinger picture is wrong. You can not just exponentiate the integral of the Hamiltonian precisely because $H_1(t)$ at different $t$ may not commute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following I set $\hbar=1$. Let's assume that in the Schrodinger picture, we have
$$i \psi_S'(t) = \big[H_0 + V_S(t)\big]\psi_S(t)$$
where we assume $H_0$ does not explicitly depend on time. If we define $\psi_S(t) = e^{-iH_0 t} \psi_I(t)$, then substitution yields
$$H_0 e^{-iH_0 t} \psi_I(t) + ie^{-iH_0 t} \psi_I'(t) = \big[H_0 + V_S(t)\big]e^{-iH_0t}\psi_I(t)$$
$$\implies i\psi_I'(t) = V_I(t) \psi_I(t), \qquad V_I(t) = e^{iH_0 t} V_S(t) e^{-iH_0t}$$

Because $V_I$ depends on time, we cannot simply exponentiate it to obtain a solution like we could with $H_0$. Integrating the expression with respect to time yields the integral equation
$$\psi_I(t) = \psi_I(0) -i \int_0^t \mathrm dt' \  V_I(t') \psi_I(t')\tag{$\star$}$$
Defining the interaction picture propagator $U_I$ such that $\psi_I(t) = U_I(t) \psi_I(0)$, this can be expressed as
$$ U_I(t) = \mathbf 1 - i \int_0^t \mathrm dt' V_I(t') U_I(t')$$
This can be formally solved via iteration, yielding the Dyson series
$$U_I(t) = \mathbf 1 +(-i)\int_0 ^t \mathrm dt'\ V_I(t') + (-i)^2\int_0^t \mathrm dt' \int_0^{t'} \mathrm dt''\  V_I(t') V_I(t'')  + \ldots$$
where we generate each successive term by plugging the preceding one into the right-hand side of $(\star)$. Note that $V_I(t')$ and $V_I(t'')$ generically do *not* commute with one another.  One can show via standard multivariable integration that
$$\int_0^t \mathrm dt' \int_0^{t'} \mathrm dt'' \ V_I(t') V_I(t'') = \frac{1}{2!} \int_0^t \mathrm dt' \int_0^\color{red}{t} \mathrm dt'' \mathcal T\big\{V_I(t') V_I(t'')\big\} $$
where we note that the upper integral bound in the second integral has been increased to $t$ rather than $t'$, and where we define the time-ordering symbol
$$\mathcal T\big\{V_I(t') V_I(t'')\big\} := \begin{cases}V_I(t') V_I(t'')  & t' > t'' \\ V_I(t'') V_I(t') & t' < t'' \end{cases}$$
In other words, $\mathcal T\big\{V_I(t')V_I(t'')\big\}$ orders the operators so that the later (i.e. larger) time comes first.  Pulling the $\mathcal T$ symbol out of the integral and extending this to higher powers, one sees without much effort that
$$U_I(t) = \mathcal T\left\{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-i)^n}{n!}\underbrace{\int_0^t \mathrm dt' \cdots\int_0^t \mathrm dt^{(n)}}_{n\text{ times}}V_I(t') \cdots V_I(t^{(n)})\right\} \equiv \mathcal T\left\{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-i)^n}{n!}\left(\int_0^t \mathrm dt' V_I(t')\right)^n\right\}$$
$$\equiv \mathcal T\left\{e^{-i \int_0^t \mathrm dt' V_I(t')}\right\}$$

This is sometimes referred to as a *time-ordered exponential*.

---

> Suppose the Hamiltonian is $H+H_1(t)$. In the Schrodinger picture, the evolution is:
> $$|\psi(t)\rangle=e^{i(Ht+\int_0^tH_1(t)dt)}|\psi(0)\rangle$$

No, this isn't right.  The operator exponential can be understood as being formally defined by a power series, but you can see that the power series of that exponential is problematic because $H$ does not commute with $H_1$ and because $H_1(t)$ does not commute with $H_1(t')$ for $t\neq t'$.

More directly, to second order one has

$$e^{-i\big(Ht + \int_0^t \mathrm dt' \ H_1(t')\big)} \approx \mathbf 1 - i \big(Ht + \int_0^t \mathrm dt'\ H_1(t')\big) - \frac{1}{2}\big(Ht + \int_0^t \mathrm dt'\ H_1(t')\big)\big(Ht + \int_0^t \mathrm dt'' \ H_1(t'')\big) $$
The second order term is
$$-\frac{1}{2} \left[H^2 t^2 + (Ht)\int_0^t \mathrm dt'' H_1(t'') + \int_0^t \mathrm dt' H_1(t') (Ht) + \int_0^t \mathrm dt' \int_0^t \mathrm dt'' H_1(t')H_1(t'')\right]$$

It's not difficult (though it is a bit tedious) to show that this doesn't obey the Schrodinger equation if you differentiate it term-by-term, precisely because of the non-commutivity issues mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first expression might not be correct. I should have changed the basis of the Schrodinger equations instead:

$$\frac{d}{dt}e^{iHt}|\psi (t)\rangle$$

$$=e^{iHt}\frac{d}{dt} |\psi (t)\rangle +\frac{d}{dt} e^{iHt}|\psi (t) \rangle $$

$$=e^{iHt}(-i(H+H_1)|\psi (t)\rangle)- iH e^{iHt}|\psi (t)\rangle$$

$$=ie^{iHt}H_1|\psi (t)\rangle $$