# Showing that interaction and Schrödinger pictures are equivalent -- does the result hold without commutativity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, time-evolution, observables, quantum-states

I am trying to show that the interaction picture represents a valid picture. We use this picture when our Hamiltonian takes the form $H = H_0 +H_1$. "Valid" means that it should reproduce the predictions of the canonical Schrodinger picture and, following Ballentine, that this "reproducing" is implicit if we can show that the redefinitions in the new picture give the same Born rule results since our physical theory only gives probabilistic predictions.

Now if we assume that both terms are independent of time and that they commute with each other then the development is simple, as I now show. Our assumption is implicit in writing that $U(t) = e^{-i(H_0 +H_1)t/\hbar}$; without our assumptions this would have a much more complex structure as a time-ordered exponential. Note that typically when using the interaction picture, we have $H_0$ independent of time anyway, but that it commutes with $H_1$ and that $H_1$ at different times commutes need not hold. For an arbitrary observable represented by the operator $R$ we have from the Born rule in the Schrodinger picture (Schrodinger picture quantities have no subscripts) that
$$\langle R \rangle \equiv \textrm{Tr} \, {\rho(t)R} = \textrm{Tr} \,{U(t)\rho(0)U^\dagger(t)R} = \textrm{Tr} \,{e^{-i(H_0 +H_1)t/\hbar}\rho(0)e^{i(H_0 +H_1)t/\hbar}R} $$
$$\stackrel{(1)}{=} \textrm{Tr} \,{e^{-iH_0t/\hbar}e^{-iH_1t/\hbar}\rho(0)e^{iH_1t/\hbar}e^{iH_0t/\hbar}R} = \textrm{Tr} \,{e^{-iH_1t/\hbar}\rho(0)e^{iH_1t/\hbar}e^{iH_0t/\hbar}Re^{-iH_0t/\hbar}} $$
$$\stackrel{(2)}{=} \textrm{Tr} \,{e^{iH_0t/\hbar}e^{-i(H_0 +H_1)t/\hbar}\rho(0)e^{+i(H_0 +H_1)t/\hbar}e^{-iH_0t/\hbar}e^{iH_0t/\hbar}Re^{-iH_0t/\hbar}} = \textrm{Tr} \,{e^{iH_0t/\hbar}\rho(t)e^{-iH_0t/\hbar}e^{iH_0t/\hbar}Re^{-iH_0t/\hbar}}$$
$$\equiv  \textrm{Tr} \,{\rho_I(t)R_I(t)}$$
where in (1) we've used that the two terms commute to separate the exponential operator and in (2) we've observed that, since everything commutes, $e^{iH_0t/\hbar}e^{-i(H_0 +H_1)t/\hbar} = e^{-iH_1t/\hbar}$, and in the final step we've made the standard interaction picture definitions as given by Ballentine. Thus, since we've shown by the above computation that the Born rule gives the same results in each case, we can say that these pictures are equivalent.

My question is, **is this formally correct in the sense that, if we relaxed my restrictions and considered the general case involving time-ordered exponentials, we would still get the same result**? The manipulation is heavy and I couldn't follow it through. It wasn't clear to me from [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/698456/does-the-interaction-picture-assume-that-the-hamiltonians-commute) question since the justification didn't start from the Born rule.

Edit:
The problem is that it's not clear to me how one can show that with $$U(t) = \mathcal T\left\{e^{-i \int_0^t \mathrm dt' H(t')/\hbar}\right\}$$, we obtain
$$\langle R \rangle \equiv \textrm{Tr} \, {\rho(t)R} = \textrm{Tr} \, {U(t)\rho(0)U^\dagger(t)R} \stackrel{?}{=}  \textrm{Tr} \,{\rho_I(t)R_I(t)}$$
where we have the definitions
$$\rho_I(t) = e^{iH_0t/\hbar}\rho(t)e^{-iH_0t/\hbar}, \, R_I(t)= e^{iH_0t/\hbar}Re^{-iH_0t/\hbar}$$

Comment: Why do you show us the case where everything seems to work (I haven't checked). The question is very long and most of the text does not have to do with the question, if I understood it correctly. What have you tried to prove in the general case? So focusing on pure states, you should show that $\langle \psi_I(t)| O_I(t) |\psi_I(t)\rangle=\langle\psi_S(t)|O_S(t) |\psi_S(t)\rangle$, no? You don't need to go to the time evolution operators at all...Perhaps I don't get your question.

Comment: @TobiasFünke The crux of my question is can one show that $\langle R \rangle \equiv \textrm{Tr} \, {\rho(t)R} =  \textrm{Tr} \,{\rho_I(t)R_I(t)}$ is true (where the interaction picture is defined in the usual way in terms of the Schrodinger picture) when we relax the commutativity assumptions mentioned? This is necessary and sufficient for the interaction picture to be a valid picture.

Comment: But what is the problem? Can you write down the definitions you use? If I am not mistaken, this is a one-liner (at least for pure states; although the generalization should not be hard at all)...

Comment: @TobiasFünke Allow me a few moments to provide an edit to the problem.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Edit complete. Please let me know if I'm still being unclear.

Comment: Well if you take a look at $\rho_I\, R_I$...do you see that some terms cancel?

Comment: Oy I think I see it. You're saying insert $I = e^{iH_0t/\hbar}e^{-iH_0t/\hbar}$ a couple times and use cyclic properties of the trace? @TobiasFünke

Comment: You don't have to insert anything...

Comment: I don't follow then. Would you mind posting/commenting the manipulation you're referring to? @TobiasFünke

Comment: You have already noticed that $I = e^{iH_0t/\hbar}e^{-iH_0t/\hbar}$. Where is the problem?! Put $\rho_IR_I$ under the trace, use cyclic property and the equality above and you're done. I don't know what else to say, sorry...This is literally it. (or, if you meant the other way around: yes, insert the above equality twice...)

Comment: @TobiasFünke I see, thank you!

Comment: You might want to write an answer yourself then; otherwise the question will remain as "unanswered" (in case no one else will write an answer).